# How to have a parameter that is one of several enum types in a class

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a class that has several enums representing the names of different types of devices.

```
public class DeviceNames {
    public enum Microsoft {
        DeviceName1, DeviceName2, DeviceName3
    }

    public enum Apple {
        DeviceName1, DeviceName2, DeviceName3
    }
}
```

I have interfaces that different concrete devices will implement (the interface specifies ways it can communicate)

```
public interface IPDevice{
    //factory method
    Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceNames.Enum<E> deviceName);
}

public interface USBDevice{
    //factory method
    Device createNewUSBDevice(DeviceNames.Enum<E> deviceName);
}
```

And I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Device {
    String deviceName;

    protected Device(String deviceName) {
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }
}
```

And concrete implementations of the abstract class that implement one or more of the interfaces

```
public class MicrosoftDevice implements IPDevice{
    @Override
    public Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceNames.Microsoft deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString());
    }
}

public class AppleDevice implements IPDevice, USBDevice {
    @Override
    public Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceNames.Apple deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Device createNewUSBDevice(DeviceNames.Apple deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString();
    }
}
```

I want to use the enum to ensure that they only give valid device names (instead of them passing in a String)

How can I have the interface method take a parameter that can take a generic enum type but only an enum that is in the DeviceNames class?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to have domain values as enums, but if this is a hardcoded hach, II would use a single Manufacturer/Device enum which has all combines `APPL_NAME1("Apple", "Name1"), APPL_NAME2("Apple", "Name2"), MSFT_NAME1("Microsoft", "Name1")` etc.

Comment: @eckes The problem with that is that it would allow the caller to pass in any of the enums. (ie. They could pass in `APPL_NAME1` to the method in a `MicrosoftDevice`). I could get around this by throwing an exception if the wrong manufacturer is used, but I'm wondering if there a way to cause a compile error so no exception needs to get thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281914/override-method-so-that-a-parameter-allows-for-a-subclass/39281968#39281968). The accepted answer solved this question.

To quote @Andreas (the one who answered the other question)

> You make the interface itself actually take the generic parameter

The working code looks like this (The code not included here stays the same):

```
public interface IPDevice<DeviceName extends Enum> {
    //factory method
    Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceName deviceName);
}

public interface USBDevice<DeviceName extends Enum> {
    //factory method
    Device createNewUSBDevice(DeviceName deviceName);
}

public class MicrosoftDevice implements IPDevice<DeviceNames.Microsoft> {
    @Override
    public Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceNames.Microsoft deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString());
    }
}

public class AppleDevice implements IPDevice<DeviceNames.Apple>, USBDevice<DeviceNames.Apple> {
    @Override
    public Device createNewIPDevice(DeviceNames.Apple deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Device createNewUSBDevice(DeviceNames.Apple deviceName) {
        return super(deviceName.toString();
    }
}
```