# Override method so that a parameter requires a subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have an abstract super class and 2 classes that extend it

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {}

public class A extends MyAbstract {}

public class B extends MyAbstract {}
```

I have an interface which has a method that takes a subclass of MyAbstract as its parameter

```
public interface MyInterface {
    <T extends MyAbstract> void someMethod(T param);
}
```

I then have a class that implements that interface

```
public class AnotherClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    <T extends MyAbstract> void someMethod(T param) {}
}
```

But I only want to allow a specific subclass of `MyAbstract` to be used in the method.

Here are a couple of the things I tried so far:

```
<T extends A> void someMethod(T param); //doesn't override the method

void someMethod(A param); //doesn't override the method
```

Is there anyway to have a interface take a generic parameter and the implementer of that interface specify a more restricted version of that parameter or is this simply not possible?

Comment: You question embodies a contradiction in terms. A method with different parameters cannot possibly be an override, by definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you make the interface *itself* actually take the generic parameter:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyAbstract> {
    void someMethod(T param);
}
```

Then you can limit it where used:

```
public class AnotherClass<T extends A> implements MyInterface<T> {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(T param) {}
}
```

Or:

```
public class AnotherClass implements MyInterface<A> {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(A param) {}
}
```